# JSON date changed

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring, ibatis

I have a web application where user can post the message to a restful API, so that that information can be saved in the database.

My problem when the data is sent from the UI, the date sent is "effStartDate":"2016-08-13" , but when i see the date value in the java code it is showing Fri Aug 12 20:00:00 EDT 2016.

I am using AngularJS,Spring and iBatis as the ORM tool. Attached are the screen shots with data sent from UI and what i see in the backend code.

can anyone help me with this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add annotations to realize in the entity.
(Have to rely on JackJson`s jar)
and Then add in required fields 
"@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",timezone = "GMT+8")"

Comment: I tried that, Date sent from UI - "2016-08-13 00:00:00"  and Date i see in backend is "Fri Aug 12 12:00:00 EDT 2016"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this use date format from javascript code to send requests to a server by REST api.

For example:

```
effStartDate.toISOString();
```

The `toISOString()` method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format

Comment: When i try this , UI Date = "effStartDate":"2016-08-28T00:19:21.000Z" , Data seen at the backend Sat Aug 27 20:19:21 EDT 2016

Comment: Date is a fine field type for this.  You can make the JSON parse by using ObjectMapper.setDateFormat 
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z");
myObjectMapper.setDateFormat(df);

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the date as a string. Something like this 
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")